# WP Ultimate Member hook/function not running

Tags: wordpress

I am using the Ultimate Member plugin and trying to trigger things after the registration form is filled in successfully.

As a test, I am simply creating a new post if the hook is run: `um_registration_complete`.

https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/1234-umregistrationcomplete

```
function my_registration_complete( $user_id, $args ) {

  // Create post object
  $my_post = array(
    'post_title'    => 'function working',
    'post_content'  => 'hello world.',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => 1,
  );

  // Insert the post into the database
  wp_insert_post( $my_post );

}

add_action( 'um_registration_complete', 'my_registration_complete', 10, 2 );
```

Nothing happens after a successful registration. No post.
I tried adding `die();` as a test to break the site on purpose if the hook runs, still nothing.

How best to debug this issue, I see nothing wrong with how I am using the hook but still it's not running.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my issue, and something I should have mentioned originally too. I am using the roots.io framework.

Functions etc namespaced, my `add_action` function name was not namespaced. Here is the working line:

```
add_action( 'um_registration_complete', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\my_registration_complete', 10, 2 );
```